# Why Ubuntu not locking the screen after timeout?

Tags: system-settings

[image]

Are these settings enough to lock screen after 1 minute of inactivity?
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
I have diffirent apps installed on my computer. I don't which one of them prevents from locking (If they do, of course)

Comment: Are you waiting the full one minute *after* the screen blanks?

Comment: The screen is not even getting blanks. Today it works ok, comparing to yesterday. I don't know what changes. I haven't restarted computer. I have the same apps opened.